# jQuery selector not working causing the function to not run

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to have this message pop when you submit a form. The HTML and jQuery snippets are below.

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-submit mb-1">
    Submit!
</button>
<div class="form-submitted d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <p class="p-2">Your form has been submitted&#33;</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var $submitMessage = $('.form-submitted');
var $submitBtn = $('form button');

$submitMessage.hide();
$submitBtn.click(function() {
    $submitMessage.slideDown(2000);
});
```

For some reason, the div is still on the screen when I load the page. What's going on?

Comment: when form is submitted the pages reload.

Comment: Have you tried CSS instead to hide the message div on the page load

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$submitMessage.hide();` why not just do `<div class="form-submitted" style="display: none;"></div>` ?

When the button is clicked it does submit the form and reload the page if the form action is to itself. The best thing to do in your case would to post the data via ajax and on a successful callback with your slidedown.

something like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/yourendpoint',
  data: yourdataobject,
  success: function(data) {
    $submitMessage.slideDown(2000);
  },
  error: function(data) {
    yourErrorHandler(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//you jquery code goes here});
```

This waits for HTML page to be ready for events/actions/methods to be able to work on them.

This shall fix your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var $submitMessage = $('.form-submitted');
 var $submitBtn = $('form button');

 $submitMessage.hide();
 $submitBtn.click(function() {
    $submitMessage.slideDown(2000);
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on submit button, page is reloading, so  $('.form-submitted') will not going to hide.

You need to change button type='submit' to 'button'

you need to use ajax for that.

```
 $submitMessage.hide();
 $.post(YourPostUrl, YourParameters, function(){
          $submitMessage.slideDown(2000);
    });
```